# Custom 503 on Openshift for Ghost Blog

Tags: python, node.js, .htaccess, openshift, ghost-blog

I found a way to do it with Python but I don't know how to make this work with a Ghost blog in OpenShift. Could someone who is more familiar help me out? I'm at a loss currently. https://gist.github.com/vimishor/7944395

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
```

Comment: Will this persist through reboots of the application though, thats my problem.